# Swift 2.1 guard vs. if let

Tags: swift, swift2, option-type

In this example, which would be the appropriate convention to use?

```
static func getWindowSize(scene: SKScene) -> NSRect? {
    if let windowSize = scene.view?.bounds {
        return windowSize
    } else {
        print("Could not get window size")
    }
    return NSRect()
}
```

OR

```
static func getWindowSize(scene: SKScene) -> NSRect? {
    guard let windowSize = scene.view?.bounds else {
        print("Could not get window size")
        return NSRect()
    }
    return windowSize
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do:

```
static func getWindowSize(scene: SKScene) -> NSRect? {
    return scene.view?.bounds ?? NSRect()
}
```

Btw. since your code always returns valid `NSRect`, you can return `NSRect` instead of `NSRect?`

Answer (score 2):

In your example it is really no difference because you do not use the `windowSize` anywhere other than return. But if you would have some more code using the `windowSize`, doing more and more `if let` pushes your code tab further. Also you then need to remember when the scope with that variable ends which sometimes might be hard. Guard lets you keep the flow simple, since you are sure the windowSize is correct value in the whole block, not only in the `if let` positive block.

But to simplify your current code, since you are returning an Optional, in case you couldn't get the window size you could return nil instead of empty `NSRect()`.

Your `guard` example is okay (you could change `return NSRect()` to `return nil`), but in `if let` I would change it to:

```
static func getWindowSize(scene: SKScene) -> NSRect? {
    if let windowSize = scene.view?.bounds {
        return windowSize
    } else {
        print("Could not get window size")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can live without the `print` this reduces to `return scene.view?.bounds`.

Comment: Yea guessed the print is needed here for his debugging ^^